# Remove everything after character if followed by number

Tags: php, regex

Sorry for the complex title!

Say for example I have the following string:

```
package-name-1.0.5.00124.4
```

I want to split this string so that i just have 'package-name'.

At the moment I'm using the following code, which doesn't work if the package name has a dash:

```
list ($var) = explode ("-", $var);
```

I need to explode the string if the dash is followed by numbers, something like the following:

```
list ($var) = explode ("-[0-9]", $var);
```

I'm no good with Regex so that's why I'm here, thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you could choose to go about this. One would be [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), replacing a trailing dash plus numbers-and-dots with the empty string:

```
$name = preg_replace('/-[0-9.]+$/', '', $var);
```

Another would be to use [`rtrim`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to do the same:

```
$name = rtrim($var, '0123456789.-');
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/BLRJS)**.

Comment: a dot inside square brackets is a literal dot. Should be `/-[0-9].*/`

Comment: @Jon thanks for your answer, but it doesn't seem to be working for me, the string doesn't get altered with your code.

Comment: @nickf: It's a literal dot on purpose.

Comment: @Cristian: It doesn't alter the string, it puts the result in `$name`. If you want to alter the string assign back to `$var` as in your examples.

Comment: it's working perfectly using @nickf 's ammendment. Thanks so much! is there any resource you'd suggest reading to learn regex? I can't get the hang of it! Thanks again

Comment: @Jon I did do that, I'm not that ignorant ;)

Comment: you should match -\d+\. , to cope with package names like *rambo-2-1.0*

Comment: @Cristian: I got the parameter order for `rtrim` wrong (fixed now), but otherwise both will work -- see the link. I 'm not sure what went wrong when you tried it.

Comment: more elegant way: `$name = preg_replace('/-\d.*/', '', $var);`

Comment: @guido: Actually the current expression matches that just fine.

Comment: @JanTuroň: That will not work correctly for a package name like `rambo-2`.

Comment: @Jon: the OP clearly says *if the dash is followed by numbers*

Comment: @Jon: whoops sorry, it was intended to go in other answer

Comment: @JanTuroň: The OP is human, therefore it is entirely possible that he overlooked something. In any case I fail to see why you would *not* prefer a regex that works correctly in all cases.

Comment: @Jon: Assumptions are the main source of misunderstanding. I don't even assume that OP is human.